# Calculate the expected value of this game

Tags: probability, expectation, game-theory

Every night, different meteorologist gives the probability of rain for the next day. To judge their predictions, we use the following scoring system: if a meteorologist predicts rain with the probability $\color{blue}{p^*}$ and is right, that meteorologist receives a score of $1-(1-p)^2$; if wrong, they receive a score of $(1-p)^2$. After a while we will be able to know which meteorologist is the best. Assumming one meteorologist knows the scoring system, what is the best way for them to maximise their expected value?

I know they probably should predict with a 50% accuracy everytime because that is where both fucntion intersect but what is the formula i should use to get to the right answer?

Comment: If he thinks probability of rain is greater than $\frac 1 2$, he should report $p=1$; if it's $<\frac 1 2$ he should report $p=0$ and report $\frac 1 2$ otherwise not to be lying all the time.

Comment: do you mean he gets $1-(1-p)^2$ if it rains and $(1-p)^2$ if it doesn't rain ?

Comment: @spexel what does it mean to say that he is right if he predicts a 30% chance of rain ?

Comment: @spexel I googled the exercise. There is a distinction between the predicting probability and the p of the score. I will edit your question. http://fac-staff.seattleu.edu/difranco/web/Math_351_Fall_2009/Homework/Homework5soln.pdf

Comment: if he says it's going to rain tomorrow at a .3 probability, if he is right, his score woul be $1-(1- 0.3)^2$

Comment: How did you found that homework?

Comment: @spexel I just googled the first line of the exercise.

Comment: @calculus:  That is not how I read the question.  I think the $p$ of the prediction is the same as the $p$ of the score.  What is different is the forecaster's actual belief $p^*$.

Comment: @Henry Feel free to edit the question. But we all have come to nowhere assuming p of the prediction is the same as the p  of the score.

Answer (score 0):

If the meteorologist's belief is $p^*$ then the expected gain from predicting $p$  is $$p^* (1-(1-p)^2)+(1-p^*)(1-p)^2$$ which can be rewritten as $$ p^*+(1-2p^*)(1-p)^2$$ and so depending on the sign of $p^*-\frac12$ it is maximised when $p=1$ or $p=0$ in the natural way (as A.S. has said in the comments).

If $p^*\gt \frac{1}{2}$ then the expected value with $p=1$ is then $p^*$, while if $p^*\lt \frac{1}{2}$ then the expected value with $p=0$ is then $1-p^*$.  If $p^*= \frac{1}{2}$ then all values of $p$ give the same expected value of $\frac12$.  These might be combined into a maximum  expected value of $$\tfrac12 +\left|p^* - \tfrac12 \right|.$$